# can anybody tell what wrong with `mysqli_num_rows` function in this code please?

Tags: php, mysqli

I think the error is with SQL query or just the `numrows` funtion?
A few more things might be wrong because i've made alot of changes and am totally confused now.
Can anybody tell what is wrong with `mysqli_num_rows` in this code please?
Thanks in advance.

```
            <?php
                $i=0;
                $key=$_GET['abc'];
                $ex=explode(" ", $key);
                $query="SELECT * FROM search";

                /*foreach ($ex as $val)
                {
                    $i++;
                    if($i == 1)

                        $query .="keywords like '%$val%' ";
                        else
                        $query .="or keywords like '%$val%' ";

                }*/
                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","search");
                if (!$con)

                        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

                        else

                        echo "Connected successfully";

                mysqli_select_db($con,"search");

                $queryy=mysqli_real_query($con,$query);
                $nr =@mysqli_query($con, $queryy);
                $row=mysqli_num_rows($nr);

                if($row>0)
                {
                    while($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryy))
                    {
                        $id=$r['id'];
                        $title=$r['title'];
                        $description=$r['description'];
                        $keywords=$r['keywords'];
                        $link=$r['link'];

                        echo "<h2> <a href='$link'>$title</a></h2> $description <br /><br />";

                    }
                }
                else
                    echo "no results found for \"<b>$key</b>\" ";   
            ?>
```

Comment: you most likely should be seeing a "1" as an error here when using `mysqli_error($con)`, but you didn't use that error handling method.

Comment: _Small Note_ You dont need `mysqli_select_db($con,"search");` if you put the database name in parameter 4 of `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxxxx","xxxxxxx","search");`

Comment: I have never used `mysqli_real_query()` but [the documentation is here and if gives a useful suggestion of how to check if there is a resultset to process](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php)

Comment: can you please explain?? m beginner .. cant understand @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: thanq @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> $queryy=mysqli_real_query($con,$query);
> $nr =@mysqli_query($con, $queryy);
> $row=mysqli_num_rows($nr);
> ```

- [`mysqli_real_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-query) takes a query string and returns a `boolean` to indicate whether or not it was successful. The result can then be accessed through [`mysqli_store_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli.store-result) or [`mysqli_use_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli.use-result).
- [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) takes a query string and either returns a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/mysqli-result) object (in this case as it is a SELECT query) or a `boolean` to indicate success or failure. The result object can then be passed to other functions.

In your code, you pass the boolean indicator from the first function in place of a query string to the second function. This will obviously fail, and you shouldn't try to execute two queries anyway. You should simply remove the first one.

You should also remove the `@` error suppression and do proper error checking instead. For example:

```
$result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
if ($result)
{
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows ($result);
    if ($rows > 0)
    {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result))
        {
             // Do stuff
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "no results...";
    }
}
else
{
    // Query failed.
}
```

You will notice that I have given the variables more meaningful names. Note also that the [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc) function takes a result parameter, not a query string.

---

**Note also** that for anything more complicated than a simple `SELECT *` query, you should probably be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements) instead.

---

You should also escape your HTML output using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to avoid XSS attacks and generally embarrassing output failures. E.g.:

```
$link_h  = htmlspecialchars ($link);
$title_h = htmlspecialchars ($title);
echo "<h2> <a href='$link_h'>$title_h</a></h2>...";
```

And so on.